# chef vault search syntax

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm wondering how to constrain the nodes that chef vault works with using the the search syntax -eg;

```
knife vault create secrets dnsimple -S '*:*'
```

For instance if I wanted to restrict the nodes that had the above secret to only the nodes that have "dns" in them would I use:

```
knife vault create secrets dnsimple -S '*dns*'
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the [Chef search syntax](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html). Assuming you mean nodes with `dns` in the name that would be `name:*dns*`.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax would be to use following in the command line

```
knife vault create secrets dnsimple -S '*:*'
```

Do not use the command if you have a large number of machines in the group.

And if you plan using it in the cookbook then include the dnsimple recipe

include_recipe 'dnsimple::default'

Comment: include_recipe and chef-vault are entirely unrelated.